# What options are available to me to find lists that were created using a specific list definition?

Tags: list, object-model, list-definition

I have many lists, some of which were created using a custom and now-obsolete list definition. I need a programmatic way of finding out which lists were created using that old definition.

Currently my workaround is to check the `ServerTemplate` attribute in the list's `PropertiesXml`:

```
SPList.PropertiesXml.Contains(string.Format("ServerTemplate=\"{0}\"", oldTemplateId))
```

Is there a method to do this without iterating through lists and comparing properties? Are there any other properties I can use to identify which list definition the list is based on?

Comment: Question is unclear on what exactly the problem is causing users to post answers that are unsatisfactory to you.

Comment: @tylerrrr07: I've already attempted to clarify by adding the [object-model] tag (following the two PowerShell answers, despite the C# code sample), but I'm really at a loss as to what extra information I can add. I've already got some background, an example of what I'm doing, and a request for a any better methods to get the same (or similar) information. If you have any suggestions for additional clarification then they're more than welcome.

Comment: The off-topic (PowerShell) answers have been re-upvoted after my downvotes; this means anyone looking at this in future may end up chasing wild geese, which is unfortunate.

Comment: Honestly on a first pass I thought you were looking for a way to query the site for lists based on list definition but I think the focus is more on the properties because you already have an SPList? I'm not sure if you are looking for a different way to get "ServerTemplate" or just an alternate way to identify a List Definition via the API. The answers provided give you ways to access list properties but don't tell you what properties would be useful which is where I'm sure you think they fell short. Your question is actually very good. We are just doing too much guessing to effectively help.

Comment: @tylerrrr07: I'm looking for *any* way to identify lists created using a certain definition, my only caveats being that the answer should a) Use the Object Model, b) Be more efficient than my current rather bodgy workaround. All of which I've tried to make clear in my question. :| As it stands, this question isn't of use to anyone with this problem at present or in future, so I'll leave until tomorrow and then delete it if there are no further answers.

Comment: I edited your question to what I thought would at least be slightly clearer (pending peer review) - Just out of curiosity did you look at SPList.TemplateFeatureId ? Would this be of any use to you?

Comment: @tylerrrr07: I don't believe your edits will help avoid answers such as the below (but thanks for trying); since the edits are largely aesthetic, and the misunderstandings are at a more basic level (i.e. that vague hand-waving at an almost-related subject is not an answer). I've already commented on `TemplateFeatureId` below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [SPList.BaseTemplate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.basetemplate.aspx) property tells you what list definition was used to create a given list.

Also, LINQ is by far the most efficient way to query all the lists in your site -- and this could obviously be extrapolated to query all lists within an entire site collection too (see [Example 2 here](http://solutionizing.net/2009/01/18/linq-tip-enumerable-oftype/)). Creating nested "foreach" loops to manually enumerate all your sites, webs and lists can be very onerous on your system, be warned!

Here is some sample code to get you started:

```
var obsoleteLists = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists.Cast<SPList>().Where(l => (int)l.BaseTemplate == 10000);

foreach (SPList list in obsoleteLists) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine("The {0} list was created using the {1} definition.", list.Title, list.BaseTemplate);
}
```

> NOTE: This code assumes that your custom list definition has an ID of
>   10000. You could replace this with any of the built-in [SPListTemplateType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splisttemplatetype.aspx) values if you were querying for any OOTB list
>   types, e.g. SPListTemplateType.Announcements

Comment: A quick glance in SPM seems to indicate that BaseTemplate is blank for all lists created with any custom list definition; hence I'd ruled it out before. However, this appears to be because SPM is attempting to convert it to the enumeration. Further digging in Server Explorer shows the true stored ID value. You sir, are my saviour. :)

Comment: +1 for good answer but "Also, LINQ is by far the most efficient way to query all the lists in your site!" Are you sure about that? Whats happening in the background? I suspect that its doing exactly the same as a for loop over entire collection - LINQ can only be more efficient for somemthing like SQL/CAML where the LINQ operator can be converted into something the underlying store can work with - http://www.sharepointblues.com/2010/09/08/linq-to-sharepoint-performance-pitfalls/

Comment: This SO post explains it well - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4267783/does-linq-enhance-the-performance-by-eliminating-looping

Comment: There are bucketloads of posts and articles on the web with comparisons of foreach loops vs linq queries. The results are almost always contradictory though so it probably depends on the situation in which you're using the linq/loop. Perhaps I was a "little" excited when I disclaimed that LINQ is always faster, but I generally tend to place more faith in Microsoft's LINQ developers and testers than I do in my own unit tests. Either way, the question above is about code that will only ever run once, so inthat case it's best to go down the path of whichever is easiest to read 'n write.

Comment: @Ryan: At this point I'd be happy even if the answer used COM.

Comment: I feel like such a noob but I totally learned something about enums today. Great answer!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to tweak this code to get what you are looking for.

http://blogs.pointbridge.com/Blogs/monnette_jeff/Pages/Post.aspx?_ID=22

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, but that article appears to fetch the list's fields (not properties).

Answer (score 0):

this may be of help to get you started - [Viewing SharePoint properties as lists, tables and CSV in PowerShell](http://get-spscripts.com/2010/09/viewing-sharepoint-properties-as-lists.html)

You can also dig into the list properties using [SPManager](http://spm.codeplex.com/).

[UPDATE] from first link item -

```
$web = Get-SPWeb http:/fooSite/
$list = $web.Lists["fooList"] 
$list  #this would give you all the properties including the TemplateFeatureId, SchemaXML, BaseTemplate, PropertiesXML, ServerTemplate, etc..
```

Comment: If I was having difficulties retrieving properties in PowerShell in general, then perhaps. However, that article doesn't even mention list definitions as far as I can tell and as you can see from my code sample, I'm using the Object Model...

Comment: SPM is a great little tool; I used it to find the `ServerTemplate` attribute I mentioned above. But unfortunately I can't integrate with it programmatically.

Comment: `TemplateFeatureId` could be useful in some circumstances, but unfortunately there is more than one list definition in the feature in my case. Here's the OM equivalent for anyone who would find it useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.templatefeatureid.aspx

Comment: If the PowerShell version of the object does indeed include the `ServerTemplate` property you say it does, then it is unique to Powershell, as there is no equivalent OM property.

Comment: a PowerShell script output showing ServerTemplate: ...FeatureId="00bfea71-de22-43b2-a848-c05709900100" ServerTemplate="100" Created="20120208 12:33:41" Modified="20120208 12:34:06" .

Comment: there's an example of querying the lists property here too - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx

Comment: That looks like the output of one of the XML properties; one of which I already use in the sample code in my question. SPSiteDataQuery (that you linked to) is for retrieving data across a site collection using the template ID (there are possible workarounds using this, but they would miss empty lists). I can only admire your determination (and thanks) but I'm not sure you can help me in this instance.

Comment: I may have misread your question above - to clarify, you are looking for lists with the same list definition across the site collection?